# Python - get while loop to run a certain amount of times

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop

I am trying to get a `while` loop to function `dur` amount of times, however when I run it it just sits there, I assume calculating, seemingly forever. It is a simple script that shouldn't take very long to run, so I assume I have messed up the `while` loop.

Here is the code:
    #Compound interest calculator

```
print "Enter amounts without $, years or %"
loan = input("How many dollars is your loan? ")
dur = input("How many years is your loan for? ")
per = input("What percent is the interest on your loan? ")
percent = per / 100
count = 0

#First calculation of amount
first = loan * percent
count = count + 1

#Continued calculation occurs until count is equal to the duration set by the user
while count <= dur:
    out = first * percent

#Prints output
output = out + loan
print str(output)
```

Comment: You need to increment count in the `while` loop, otherwise it will never exit.

Comment: add: `count = count + 1` in the `while` loop.

Comment: @isedev you are correct, OP using `out`

Comment: Note that `out` will have exactly the same value after the first iteration as it has after the 1000th, since neither `first` not `percent` change in the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your code.

1. `percent` will always be `0`, because you are using integer division. Try `percent = per / 100.0` instead.
2. As others have noted, you have to increase `count` to end the loop.
3. Without changing either `first` nor `percent` in the loop, the calculated value of `out` will be the same in each iteration of the loop. Try `first = first * percent` instead.

Finally, you do not need the loop at all. Just do this:

```
output = loan * (1 + per/100.)**dur
```

Comment: Thnaks, that works much better, but could you explain what the `1 + ` does? I know it's necessary because I tried running it without it, but I'm not quite sure what it does.

Comment: The `1+` turns e.g. `0.03` (for 3%) into `1.03`, so you can just calculate `loan * 1.03` instead of `loan + loan * 0.03`. The power operator `**` then turns this into `loan * 1.03 * 1.03 * ... * 1.03`.

Comment: @mm865 If this solved your problem, you can 'accept' this answer (or another, if you like them better) to mark the question as being resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You need to increment `count` in the while loop, otherwise the stop condition (`count <= dur`) will never happen.

```
while count <= dur:
    # do something
    count += 1
```

If you know in advance the number of times you want to do something you could also use:

```
for i in xrange(dur): # use range if python3
   # do something
```

Also note that your code has another problem: you're not really calculating compund interest. At every step you recalculate `first * percent` instead of adding `percent` to the previous interest. You should do:

```
# First calculation of amount
out = loan * percent
count = count + 1

while count <= dur:
    out *= (1.0 + percent)
    count += 1
```

Comment: Thanks! I only just realised that it wasn't compound.

Comment: `out *= percent` This will make `out` smaller and smaller in each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

`count` never changes within the loop. Do this

```
while count <= dur:
    out = first * percent
    count += 1
```